# ValidationException Message When Reading JSON

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have problem when reading JSON using the Play framework JSON library.

I have case class like this:

```scala
case class Id(value: UUID)

object Id {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Id] = new OFormat[Id] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Id] =
      for {
        uuid <- (json \ "id").validate[UUID]
      } yield Id(uuid)

    override def writes(id: Id): JsObject =
      JsObject(
        Seq(
          "id" -> JsString(id.value.toString)
        ))
  }
}
```

I am reading this JSON payload:

```
{
    // other data
    ....
    "id" : "9474df4e-5d80-461f-9de5-a3d4c638485a"
}
```

But I get this error message:

```
{"error":"JsResultException(errors:List((/id,List(ValidationError(List(\"9474df4e-5d80-461f-9de5-a3d4c638485a\" is not an object),WrappedArray())))
```

I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Rather make `Id` a Value class

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
case class Id(id: UUID)

object Id {
  implicit val formats = Json.format[Id]
}

object Example extends App {
  val raw =
      """
        |{
        |  "id" : "9474df4e-5d80-461f-9de5-a3d4c638485a"
        |}
      """.stripMargin


  println(Json.parse(raw).as[Id])
}
```

which outputs

```
Id(9474df4e-5d80-461f-9de5-a3d4c638485a)
```

Note how we renamed the field from `value` to `id`:

```
case class Id(id: UUID)
```

If preferring to keep the model with `value` field

```
case class Id(value: UUID)
```

then try

```
case class Id(value: UUID)

object Id {
  implicit val idWrites = new Writes[Id] {
    def writes(id: Id) = Json.toJson(id.value)
  }

  implicit val idReads: Reads[Id] =
    (JsPath \ "id").read[UUID].map(Id.apply)
}
```